# How to restrict ssh tunnel authority to a certain port?

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I have a program running on remote server port 9999. As it don't support any kind of encryption and auth, I'm using the ssh tunnel to access to it.

This is the command I am using:

```
ssh -L 9999:localhost:9999 user@remotehost
```

In order to keep this tunnel alive. I write a ssh script to monitor and restart it if anything went wrong. So, I have to store the password in the script.

But, considering the possibility this client-server is hacked. I think it is better if I can restrict this tunnel to a min authority.

So, is it possible to restrict the remotehost user can only used ssh tunnel forwarding to port 9999?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> In order to keep this tunnel alive. I write a ssh script to monitor and restart it if anything went wrong.

You should look into using [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) instead.

> So, I have to store the password in the script.

You should use public key authentication instead of a password.

> So, is it possible to restrict the remotehost user can only used ssh tunnel forwarding to port 9999?

First, make sure the user can't open an interactive shell on the **server** machine. Just create a specific account that is only used for opening this tunnel if you're not using one already. Set the default shell for this account to `/sbin/nologin` (or `/bin/false` if the former does not exist)

```
useradd tunnel
usermod -s /sbin/nologin tunnel
```

You should go on the **client** machine and generate an ssh key pair and copy the public key to the server.

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id tunnel@server
```

Finally, on the **server**, restrict the ability to tunnel anything but localhost:9999 using the authorized_keys file. <strike>Append</strike> Prepend the following to the authorized key that was uploaded with `ssh-copy-id`.

```
no-pty,permitopen="localhost:9999"
```

The no-pty is another security setting that disallows opening an interactive shell. The resulting line looks something like this:

```
no-pty,permitopen="localhost:9999" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1y...Rdo/R user@clientbox
```

There might be other useful options you can set in the `authorized_keys file`. For more information, read [man sshd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd).

In addition, you can also lock down the account in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` via a Match block for the account:

```
Match User tunnel
   ForceCommand /sbin/nologin # An additional configuration to disable any shell command, superfluous when the user's shell is already set to `/sbin/nologin`
   AllowAgentForwarding no
   AllowTcpForwarding local # Disallow port forwarding of remote ports, superfluous when using the `permitopen` restriction in authorized_keys
   AllowStreamLocalForwarding no # Probably not necessary, as the user needs to have access rights to access the AF_UNIX port
   X11Forwarding no # Because some default configuration files, e.g. from Debian, set it to yes
# Beware: Match does not end with indentation!
```

---

These are only tips to improve your current ssh tunnel setup. As Dennis suggested, there are other, more elegant tunnelling solutions you should consider.

Comment: ooh, permitopen, never knew of that. I still think using ssh for this is wrong though. Shouldn't you prepend that setting though?

Comment: I agree that this is not the right tool for the job. Thanks for spotting the append mistake.

Comment: I have changed to use stunnel, but still learn a lot from this. Thank you both for your great help!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>No, that is not possible. You can disable port forwarding, but that disables forwarding of any port, there's no per-port setting.</strike>

Yes, this is possible by prepending `permitopen="localhost:9999"` to the key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server, see the sshd manpage (thanks Kenny!). You'll also want to force a command that does nothing but sleep, to make sure that any attacker can't get a shell (and thus remove that restriction, and do other bad things).

That said, ssh is the wrong way of doing this. Why not use [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html) to make the service available over ssl? Or set up a VPN connection between the two machines with [openvpn](http://openvpn.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at the `autossh` tool.

- http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autossh

Man page is available here:

- http://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh

I use it to keep ports to an IMAP and SMTP server open that are behind a firewall. For example:

```
% autossh -M 0 -f -N -L 2025:localhost:25 -L 2143:localhost:143 \
          myuser@remoteserver
```

Looks to be in most of the larger linux distros repositories too.